# Inherit attributes from multiple parents/superclasses in Java

Tags: java

I'm learning by solving some exercises and I have to create an Android App using Java, this app has 3 main classes which are Car, Boat and Tow. These 3 classes share some attributes , for example, Car and Tow both have a Licence Plate and both Car and Boat have a load weight. Right now what I'm doing is creating two abstract classes, Vehicle and VehicleWithPlate, where Car inherits from VehicleWithPlate and Boat inherits from Vehicle. VehicleWithPlate inherits from Vehicle.

This might not even be the best approach, but the thing now is that I need to implement the load weight into one of these superclasses, and create a VehicleWithWeight is not the best option, since if a vehicle has both weight and a plate, there would be a conflict. I know a way to "implement" multiple inheritance in Java is using interfaces, and I know interfaces just implement abstract methods, not attributes . What would be the best approach to do this? My solution so far has been to implement the loadWeight property into Vehicle and Boat individually, but that doesn't look as clean.

**Car**

```
public class Car extends VehicleWithPlate{

    private float loadWeight;

    public Car(String plate, int passengersNum, int maxPassengers, float loadWeight) {
        super(plate, passengersNum, maxPassengers);
        this.loadWeight= loadWeight;
    }

    public float getLoadWeight() {
        return loadWeight;
    }
}
```

**Boat**

```
public class Boat extends Vehicle{
    private float loadWeight;

    public Barco(int passengersNum, int maxPassengers, float loadWeight) {
        super(passengersNum, maxPassengers);
        this.loadWeight= loadWeight;
    }

    public float getLoadWeight() {
        return loadWeight;
    }

}
```

**Vehicle**

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
    protected int passengersNum;
    protected int maxPassengers;

    public Veiculo(int passengersNum, int maxPassengers){
        this.passengersNum= passengersNum;
        this.maxPassengers= maxPassengers;
    }
}
```

**VehicleWithPlate**

```
public abstract class VehicleWithPlate extends Vehicle {
    protected String plate;

    public VehicleWithPlate (String plate, int passengersNum, int maxPassengers) {
        super(passengersNum, maxPassengers);
        this.plate= plate;
    }

    public String getPlate() {
        return plate;
    }
}
```

Maybe there's something I'm missing, and I know that repeating some code is not the end of the world, but I'm really curious as a student for a professional approach to something this basic.

Comment: You should totally remove `VehicleWithPlate` in my oppinion and just add `plateNumber` in car

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the difference between design by composition and design by inheritance: [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance?wprov=sfti1). Sounds a lot like you really have a few classes here. A `LicensePlate` class, a `LoadWeight` class, and all of your vehicle classes that you mentioned before. The two new classes are all “has-a” type relationships, as opposed to "is-a" type relationships (A `Car` has-a `LicensePlate`, a `Boat` has-a `LoadWeight`). Hope this helps!

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can just extract the weight property to an interface:

```
public interface Weighted {
    float getLoadWeight()
}
```

That way, you can upcast to "Weighted" when required, but will still have to implement the property individually